# Phase plot in R

Tags: r, graph, time-series, non-linear-regression

I want to make a phase plot like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait from an non-linear time series in R, Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your chances of getting an answer will greatly increase if you provide a simple, self-contained example of your problem. This would include toy input data, your code, any error messages, and expected output. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may be helpful.  Please bear in mind that SO is a problem solving community, not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't given many details, but I suggest you look at the package phaseR.
I use it to draw isoclines and a flowfield of predator-prey models.
My graphs look like this (right one):

[image]